# Counting the number of lines that have the same date in each lines

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables as follow:

-One subscription can have multiple billings

-One billing can have one subscription

Please see example pictures of the tabs:

[image: Subscription Tab]       [image: Billing tab]

now my first goal was to regroup number of billings based on creation date and billing date, so  I'm using this mysql request:

```
SELECT creation_date,billing_date,count(billing_id) 
FROM subscription,billing 
WHERE subscription.subscription_id = billing.subscription_id 
GROUP BY billing_date,creation_date
```

in order to get this result:

[image: Export result]

And my goal would be to have this result :

[image]

In other words, I would like to have for each lines of this mysql request, the number of subscriptions that share the same creation as the one on the field "creation_date" of the request.
I tried my best to be as explicit as possible and I know this is a bit tricky, so hopefully I made it clear enough.

Please note that in my example, every subscription get a billing everyday, which is not something to be based on (I cannot use the "number of billings fields" as my answer

Mysql version   is 5.6.44

Comment: Just copy the `count()`.  You have duplicated that column.

Comment: as mentioned, the number of billings is not to be based on, I've added a billing everyday for each subscription in my example but its not like that in the real environement

Comment: @AndRowID: you should provide sample data that is really representative of the use case that your describe.

Comment: it can be like this ! just a coincidence that the columns have the same values, not something to use as a rule

Comment: Probably just `count(distinct billing_id), count(distinct subscription_id)` in the query you now have.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Mike this would count souscriptions multiple times as it would count distinct subs per lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a join

```
SELECT a.number_of_billings, a.creation_date, a.billing_date, 
       COALESCE(b.number_of_subs, 0) AS number_of_subs
FROM (SELECT creation_date,billing_date,COUNT(billing_id) AS number_of_billings
      FROM subscription,billing 
      WHERE subscription.subscription_id = billing.subscription_id 
      GROUP BY billing_date,creation_date) AS a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT creation_date, COUNT(subscription_id) AS number_of_subs
 FROM subscription
 GROUP BY creation_date) AS b
ON a.creation_date = b.creation_date
```

You need the join because there are two separate grouping conditions. You want to count billing ids per distinct combination of creation_date and billing_date but you only wants subscriptions count per billing date.

Comment: Looks like what I need here! Trying in a bit and validating if this works